# get session class variable jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, class, session

Im am developing an `MVC 5` App.

I have a `UserLoginModel` class assigned to a `Session` Variable.

```csharp
public class UserLoginModel
{
  public long User_id { get; set; }
  public string Email { get; set; }
  public int Rol_id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public string LastName { get; set; }
}

private const string SessionKey = "UserLogin";
private readonly HttpContext _httpContext;

public void Save(UserLoginModel user)
{
  _httpContext.Session[SessionKey] = user;
}
```

I need to get the value of this Session `UserLogin.User_id` from jQuery. I can Access

```
var variable = '@Session["UserLogin"]';
```

But it gives me the value that it is class data type:

```
UserLoginModel
```

How can I get a specific value like `User_id`?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start with session value assignment:

```
var variable = '@Session["UserLogin"]';
```

From what I tested, this direct assignment to JS string returned full class name of `UserLoginModel`. To extract member class values from a stored model class in session variable, you need to declare local variable to hold each member's value in view page with *same data type* & cast the session as model class name like this:

```
@{
    long user_id = 0; // local variable to hold User_id value

    // better than using (UserLoginModel)Session["UserLogin"] which prone to NRE
    var userLogin = Session["UserLogin"] as UserLoginModel;

    // avoid NRE by checking against null
    if (userLogin != null)
    {
        user_id = userLogin.User_id;
    }
}

<script type="text/javascript">
    var variable = '@user_id'; // returns '1'
</script>
```

Note that `ViewBag`, `ViewData` & strongly-typed viewmodel using `@model` directive are more preferred ways over session variable to pass model values into view page.

Live example: [.NET Fiddle Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/gjjwuE)